# Simplifying this function?

Tags: calculus, limits

I feel like this is a relatively easy function to simplify but I just can't seem to do it, and I need to to find its limit at $(0,0)$. The equation is $$\frac{x^2-xy}{\sqrt x-\sqrt y}.$$I understand multiplying the numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)$ but after that I just get a jumbled mess?

Answer (score 1):

Use difference of squares in the denominator, factor the numerator, and simplify:
$$
\frac{x^2 - xy}{\sqrt x - \sqrt y} \cdot \frac{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}
= \frac{x(x - y)(\sqrt x + \sqrt y)}{x - y}
= x(\sqrt x + \sqrt y)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2-xy}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}} = \frac{x(x-y)}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}} \\ =\frac{x(x-y)}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}} \\ =\frac{x(x-y)}{x-y} \cdot \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} \\ =x(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})$$ Now you can evaluate at $(0,0)$